# How to automatically move mails to SPAM or JUNK folder instead of removing them?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, spamassasin, amavis

I have problem with amavis-new. amavis-new removes an e-mails tagged as
SPAM are removed instead of leave them tagged by SpamAssassin. Here's
/var/log/mail.log:

```
Jul 20 20:04:09 cloud-vps opendmarc[9520]: D6A8940030: mail.com none
Jul 20 20:04:09 cloud-vps postfix/qmgr[1347]: D6A8940030: from=<hubot@mail.com>, size=6018, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 20 20:04:09 cloud-vps postfix/smtpd[5589]: disconnect from mout.gmx.com[74.208.4.201] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Jul 20 20:04:19 cloud-vps amavis[27212]: (27212-02) Blocked SPAM {NoBounceOpenRelay,Quarantined}, [74.208.4.201]:56671 [80.82.28.18] <hubot@mail.com> -> <atypical@autisticstory.net>, quarantine: B/spam-Btuzpnjs5cte.gz, Queue-ID: D6A8940030, Message-ID: <21ba2dfb-9390-1c1f-4ce7-a5b3bc3e30f0@mail.com>, mail_id: Btuzpnjs5cte, Hits: 1000, size: 6082, 9557 ms
Jul 20 20:04:19 cloud-vps postfix/smtp[5595]: D6A8940030: to=<atypical@autisticstory.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=11, delays=1.2/0.03/0.54/9.3, dsn=2.5.0, status=sent (250 2.5.0 Ok, id=27212-02, DISCARD(bounce.suppressed))
Jul 20 20:04:19 cloud-vps postfix/qmgr[1347]: D6A8940030: removed
```

Have anyone ideas how to prevent removing them by amavis-new? I want to
automatically move these mails to SPAM or JUNK folder instead of
removing them.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to get Amavis and the mail store or user agent to cooperate. Amavis can be configured to tag mails that are determined to be spam. If your mail system uses sieve rules to sort mails into folders, you can check the presence of a spam tag in such a rule and sort the mail into an appropriate folder. If you're not using IMAP, the folder structure exists only in your mail user agent, and you will have to define rules there. Since I don't know which of these you have I can't be more specific here.